# SQL: Formatting phone numbers (inserting blanks)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with phone numbers that look kind of like this:

```
0041 123423423
0042 783728492
0043 832792922
0044 738922222
```

but there are also numbers that look like this:

```
00432 7462893-99
0042 873946278-100
0041 837227-1234
```

Now I want to convert all phone numbers to the following format:

```
"00[2 digits] [4 digits] [5 digits] [3 digits]"
```

Obviously not all phone numbers have the same amount of digits but it should be formatted nonetheless. This should be done via SQL (I don't think I have another possibility). I'm using MySQL.

Example for phone number:

```
Unformatted: 004912345
Formatted:   0049 1234 5
```

Thanks!

Comment: your formatted doesn't seem to match your description of how you want to converted it looks like [4 digits] [4 digits] [1 digit]

Comment: And do all numbers begin with '00' and do all phone numbers maintain same digit count (13)? If exceeds, should there be a cut-off? If lower, should there be inputting? Please revise accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you.. the last column is the result of the format

```
SELECT
  @number := REPLACE(number,' ','') as minusspace,
  @number := REPLACE(@number,'-','') as minusdash,
  @first := LEFT(@number,4) as first,
  @second := RIGHT(LEFT(@number,8),4) as second,
  @third := RIGHT(LEFT(@number,13),LEAST(LENGTH(@number)-8,5)) as third,
  @fourth := RIGHT(LEFT(@number,16),LEAST(LENGTH(@number)-13,3)) as fourth,
  TRIM(CONCAT(@first,' ',@second,' ',@third,' ',@fourth)) as formatted_phone
FROM phone
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b12238/5)